# Export APK with fewer resources automatically in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have an Android application that is built for two languages (not using the built-in language support).

I'd like to quickly export an APK file for each of the languages.

I need to change one variable in a singleton class indicating the language (this is easy), but I also need to exclude graphics from the `res` folder.

How can I do this automatically without having to remove/add graphics each time?

Comment: out of curiosity why are you choosing not to use the multi-language support provided by the system?

Comment: it's mostly a branding thing. they want to have an mexican app and a us app. i tried to convince my client, but this is how they want it. now i'm looking to minimize my effort.

Comment: If it were me I think I'd write some sort of script that would make the required changes within the project folder. a Python script should be capable of making the change in your file, and swapping out the drawables for you. AFAIK know though there is no tool that is built specifically to help you do this.